# Hollaex Plugin with Stripe API error 504 '[ECONNREFUSED]'

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am have a problem developing a Hollaex plugin with the Stripe api.

The main problem is that when I try to use it it can't initialize and give me this error in the logs

`[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request app.anbcrypto.com/plugins/stripe/currencies to http://localhost:10012/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

If you need some more details i will provide you.
Thank you all

I expect receiving a 200 code and the code initialize well.

This code is a modification of another code that works well with no errors and I just added a function so i dont know why this have errors

Comment: What Stripe API https://docs.stripe.com/api are you trying to call exactly ?

Comment: I already fixed this error.

It was that i was using a stripe webhook listening for completed payments but i forgot to mark the function as async.

This was a newbie error but thanks you all